# Atualizar combo de cidades com jQuery ao editar

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Estou com um erro na atualização do select de cidades, no create funciona corretamente, seleciono o estado e as cidades são atualizadas.
No edit não consigo que as cidades sejam atualizadas em função do estado selecionado.
Já tentei varias alternativas mas não consegui, alguém consegue me falar onde estou errando?
Segue abaixo o codigo:

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.pega_cidades = function(estado){
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'cidades/'+estado,
    dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
     if (data != null) {
       var obj = data;
       var selectbox = $('#cidade');
       selectbox.find('option').remove();
       $("#select2-chosen-2").text("SELECIONE");
       $.each(obj, function (i, d) {
         $('<option>').val(i).text(d).appendTo(selectbox);
       });
     }
    }
   });
 }; 
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.select2').select2();
 $("#cep").mask('99999-999',{placeholder: "_____-___"});
 $("#cpf").mask('999.999.999-99',{placeholder: "___.___.___-__"});
 $("#cnpj").mask('99.999.999/9999-99',{placeholder: "__.___.___/____-__"});
 $("#telefone").mask('(99) 9999-9999',{placeholder: "(__) ____-____"});
 $("#celular").mask('(99) 99999-9999',{placeholder: "(__) ____-____"});

 $("#estado").change(
  function(){
   var estado = $("#estado").val();
   
   $().pega_cidades(estado);
  }
 );
});

html dos campos

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div class="form-group required">
  <label for="bairro" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Estado:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 {if isset($errors['estado'])}has-error has-feedback{/if}">
    <select class="form-control select2" name="estado" id="estado">
      <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
      {html_options options=$estados selected=$sindicato['estado_id']}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group required">
  <label for="cidade" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Cidade:</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10 {if isset($errors['cidade'])}has-error has-feedback{/if}">
    <select class="form-control select2" name="cidade" id="cidade">
      <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
      {html_options options=$cidades selected=$sindicato['cidade_id']}
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podes colocar aqui o teu HTML?

Comment: Olá Sergio,

inseri o html, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Eu costumo fazer dessa forma:

```
function AtualizarCidade(idUf) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Cidades/_ListaPorUf",
    type: "POST",
    data: { idUf: parseInt(idUf) },
    beforeSend: function () { $("#Cidade").attr("disabled", "disabled"); var options = $("#Cidade"); options.empty(); options.append("<option value=''>Loading...</option>"); },
    success: function (returndata) {

        var options = $("#Cidade");
        options.empty();
        options.append("<option value=''>Selecione...</option>");
        $.each(returndata, function (i, item) {
            options.append("<option value='" + item.Id + "'>" + item.Nome + "</option>");
        });



}).done(function() {
    $("#Cidade").removeAttr("disabled");
});

$(document).ready(function () { $("#Uf").change(function (event) {
        AtualizarCidade($(this).val());
    });});
```

Answer (score -1):

Consegui descobrir o motivo.
Segue abaixo o que alterei para funcionar.

```js
(function($){
 $.fn.pega_cidades = function(estado){
   var url_atual = window.location.href;
   var resultado = url_atual.split("/");
   var uri = '';
   
   if(resultado[4] == 'edit'){
    uri = '../cidades/';
   }else{
    uri = 'cidades/';
   } 
   
   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:  uri+estado,
    dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data){
     if (data != null) {
       var obj = data;
       var selectbox = $('#cidade');
       selectbox.find('option').remove();
       $("#select2-chosen-2").text("SELECIONE");
       $.each(obj, function (i, d) {
         $('<option>').val(i).text(d).appendTo(selectbox);
       });
     }
    }
   });
 }; 
})(jQuery);
```